# Can't register IMAP university e-mail student account on Windows 11 and Outlook app

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, windows-11, imap

I'm a computer science student at [Universidade Federal de Minas Gerais](https://ufmg.br/international-visitors), and I'm trying to add the university mail to Outlook app on my smartphone and the Mail app  on Windows 11.
Somewhere in the past, I registered a student account on Microsoft because uni students get some free stuff through Microsoft Imagine (now unified with Azure Dev Tools), and I don't know if it is somehow related.
I'm trying the tutorial they made, but it's not working, it's complaining about my username and/or password. I know I didn't do anything wrong because I've already done this before with the e-mail specific for students of the [Computer Science Department](https://dcc.ufmg.br/en/homepage/), since we have access to some exclusive resources. That e-mail works as intended, but I do not have a Microsoft account associated with that e-mail.
There's a whole shenanigan about IMAP input and output servers and ports, but those are ok, I guess. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you're going to have to talk to your IT guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complete shot in the dark here, but I've run into this kind of thing while helping other folks troubleshoot similar issues with IMAP account logins. This is one of the main recurring themes I run into with these types of issues, but without knowing exactly how your university's email system is set up the best I can provide here is a rough guess that is likely not correct. **My best advice in your specific case is to send your university's IT department a message.**

That said, someone else may still find this information useful, so I'll put this out there anyway.

Some email service providers disallow IMAP logins from 3rd-party mail clients (as in desktop applications like Outlook) by default for "security reasons" and force you to use the provider's website instead (where they coincidentally also get to serve you advertisements).**

*Usually* these email providers also have a way to *enable* 3rd-party mail clients but bury this option deep in some hard-to-reach settings menu. This setting may just be an "enable 3rd-party email clients" switch, or you may need to generate an application-specific password or something similar.

However in your case, your student email account is managed by your university. In short, this means that *if* this setting *does* exist and *is* what's causing your issue, it may not be accessible to students. Your IT department will need to switch it for you on the back end, so you will need to message them anyway to get this resolved.

---

** To clarify, I'm not saying that there are no actual security concerns here. IMAP *absolutely can* be insecure if your provider allows connections using outdated security protocols. With that said, disabling these insecure/outdated authentication methods is laughably easy for providers to do, so providers citing this as "improving security" don't really have an excuse.